# Magento 2 Rest API get Product Category

Tags: rest, api, magento, magento2

I try to get the sku,name and category_ids for a certain product via REST call. Unfortunately I do not know how to only get the category_ids

I use following REST call:
/V1/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=sku&fields=items[sku,name,custom_attributes]&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=66-110101000

I always receive a response like this:

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "sku": "66-110101000",
        "name": "Fruchtgummi-Standardformen 10 g (100 Stück)",
        "custom_attributes": [
            {
                "attribute_code": "description",
                "value": "Fruchtgummi-Standardformen mit 10 % Fruchtgehalt aus Fruchtsaftkonzentrat, natürlichen Aromen und färbenden Pflanzenauszügen, farblich und geschmacklich bunt gemischt, in glänzend- oder matt-kaschiertem transparentem alternativ weißem Werbetütchen verpackt."
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "color",
                "value": "6923"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "category_ids",
                "value": [
                    "104"
                ]
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "has_options",
                "value": "0"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "tax_class_id",
                "value": "2"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "gift_message_available",
                "value": "0"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "color_exact",
                "value": "2508"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "package_type",
                "value": "Karton"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "shelf_life",
                "value": "ca. 12 Monate bei sachgerechter Lagerung"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "supplier_sku",
                "value": "110101000"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "product_name_supplier",
                "value": "Fruchtgummi-Standardformen 10 g (100 Stück)"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "customs_tariff_number",
                "value": "17049065"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "dimensions",
                "value": "ca. 85 x 60 mm mm"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "sw_featured",
                "value": "0"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "keyword_variable",
                "value": "Werbeartikel"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "weight_with_package",
                "value": "0.01"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "product_weight",
                "value": "1"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "use_in_crosslinking",
                "value": "1"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "in_html_sitemap",
                "value": "1"
            },
            {
                "attribute_code": "in_xml_sitemap",
                "value": "1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

All I am interessted in is to display sku, name and category_ids.
Hope you can help me how to change my API call. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following endpoint for the desired product attributes:-

GET http:///rest/default/V1/products/24-MB01?fields=sku,price,name

Please refer:-

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/rest/retrieve-filtered-responses.html

OR

You have to write your custom endpoint for the this. There is no predefined endpoint for the custom attribute selection for the product.

To developer custom endpoint you can follow the tutorial

https://www.thirdandgrove.com/creating-custom-rest-api-magento2